# zsh (256colors): default background color as foreground color

Tags: colors, zsh, zshrc, vim-powerline

I can easily switch back to the terminal default coloring scheme using `%k` (background) or `%f` (foreground). There is also the option to use `%K(default)` or `%F(default)` which produces the same results.

How can I change the foreground color to the default background color? Is this even possible without exactly naming the color-code?

Usage example: coloring the left-facing powerline separator correctly: ⮂. (leftern side is background color, rightern side is foreground color)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch foreground and background colors with the *standout mode* `%S (%s)`.

In order to print something in the default background color, you just have to set background color to default, foreground color to whatever you want as background and enable *standout mode*.

Examples:

```
print -P $' unchanged output colors'
print -P $'%f%k default colors %S standout mode %s'
print -P $'%F{blue}%K{red} blue on red %f%k'
print -P $'%S%F{blue}%K{red} red on blue %s blue on red %f%k'
print -P $'%K{default}%F{blue}%Sdefault background on blue %s%f%k'
print -P $'%K{red}%F{default}%S red on default foreground %f%k%s'
```

As you can see, it does not matter in which order the colors and modes (works the same for boldface and underline modes) are set. You can set a foreground color with `%F{color}`  before or after starting *standout mode* with `%S`, it is just used as background after `%S` until you stop *standout mode* with `%s`.

Comment: Thanks - this syntax is noodly and the examples helped :)